# estoy usando angular material y no se ve la grilla

Tags: angular, angular-material

estoy armando un grid con input, que me facilita el ingresar datos a mi tabla, solo me sale el card, pero,toda la tabla no aparece.no se si es por que me falta algun punto o coma, no creo que sean las etiquetas, por que me saldria en el editor,creo que es mas que nada algun error que no llego a ver.

```
<mat-card style="margin-top:10px;">
    <mat-card-content>
  
      <form [formGroup]="form" >
      
      <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="70px">
          <mat-grid-tile 
          [colspan]="1"
          [rowspan]="1">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>usuario</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="ingrese su username" formControlName="usuario">
            </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile 
          [colspan]="3"
          [rowspan]="5"
          [style.background]="'lightgreen'">
          <button formControlName="img" mat-raised-button color="primary">img</button>
      </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile 
          [colspan]="1"
          [rowspan]="1"
          >
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>nombre</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="nombre" formControlName="nombre">
            </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile 
          [colspan]="1"
          [rowspan]="1"
          >
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-label>apellido</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="ingrese su apellido" formControlName="apellido" >
            </mat-form-field>
          
      </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile 
          [colspan]="1"
          [rowspan]="1"
          >
         
  <mat-form-field class="sexo">
    <mat-label>sexo</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="sexo">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let sexo of sexo" [value]="sexo.value">
        {{sexo.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
      </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile >
          <button type="submit" class="separar" (click)="addUser()" mat-raised-button color="primary">aceptar</button>
          <button type="submit"  mat-raised-button color="primary">volver</button>
      </mat-grid-tile>

  </mat-grid-list>
  
  </form>      
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

no encuentro por que es que no se muestra, le di muchas vueltas, despues si me dieran su feedback, les agradeceria muchisimo, todavia estoy aprendiendo. gracias

Comment: ¿Te muestra algo la consola del navegador?